# Replace object value with other object's value of the same key with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I've got two objects, `item` and `results`.
They've both got the same keys but possibly different values, for example:

```
item.id = '50'
item.area = 'Mexico'
item.gender = null
item.birthdate = null

results.id = '50'
results.area = null
results.gender = 'Male' 
results.birthdate = null
```

What I want to do is exactly the following:

```
if (item.id == null || items.id == 0)
{
    item.id = results.id;
}
```

but I'm looking for a way to do this for each value of my `item` object. You know, without having to write a huge function if my objects happen to have a lot more keys / values.
Any ideas?

**Update :** I misunderstood my own problem and the only issue was that I didnt really understand how to get an object value given a certain key. I couldnt really use any outside scripts or divs since Im using Azure's mobile service scripts.

```
for (var key in item) {
    if(item[key] == null || item[key] == 0){
        item[key] = results[0][key] 
    }             
}
```

Comment: Loop over the object. Or if you are using jQuery, look at merge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object)

Comment: You could do this using angulars `$filter`, or using lodash, or using the native `.map`. Choose your poison!

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Thanks you were right. I saw that question before but misunderstood my own problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It could do the trick !

```js
var item = {};
var results={};

item.id = '50'
item.area = 'Mexico'
item.gender = null
item.birthdate = null

results.id = '50'
results.area = null
results.gender = 'Male'
results.birthdate = null

Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
  if (item[key] == null || item[key] == 0) {
    item[key] = results[key];
  }
})
document.getElementById('dbg').innerHTML ='<pre>' + JSON.stringify(item , null , ' ') + '</pre>';

console.dir(item);
```

```html
<div id='dbg'></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can elegantly use [lodash](http://www.lodash.com):

```js
var results = {};
var item = {};

item.id = '50';
item.area = 'Mexico';
item.gender = null;
item.birthdate = null;

results.id = '50';
results.area = null;
results.gender = 'Male'; 
results.birthdate = null;

_.merge(results, _.pick(item, _.identity));

alert(JSON.stringify(results));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Note that the requested value is now in results (and not in item). If you still need it item, clone the values into a new variable and use it.

Comment: lodash is very helpful library when working with arrays and objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the object like this. hasOwnProperty tests if it is a property defined by you and not from the base object definition.

```
for (var key in item) {
   if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       if (item[key] == null) {
           item[key] = results[key];
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Old post but if you search a more recent straightforward solution you can try [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Properties in the target object are overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key.

```
const target = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const source = { b: 4, c: 5 };

const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);

console.log(target);
// expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }

console.log(returnedTarget);
// expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to simplify it a bit.

```js
var item = {
  id: '50',
  area: 'Mexico',
  gender: null,
  birthdate: null
};
var results={
  id: '50',
  area: null,
  gender: 'Male',
  birthdate: null
};

Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
  item[key] = item[key] ?? results[key];
})

document.getElementById('dbg').innerHTML ='<pre>' + JSON.stringify(item , null , ' ') + '</pre>';

console.dir(item);
```

```html
<div id='dbg'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the one liner, here is an option:

```
{ ...item, ...Object.keys(results).reduce((pv, cv) => results[cv] == null ? pv : { ...pv, [cv]: results[cv] }, {}) };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate all the object keys, and then write assign them on each item:

```
for (var property in results) {
    if (results.hasOwnProperty(property) && !item[property]) {
        // do stuff
        item[property] = results[property]
    }
}
```